# How to change column names of autodetected partitions created by Glue Crawler?

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have bucket which is used as destination for a Kinesis Firehose stream.

Firehose automatically creates date-based prefixes on that bucket using the `yyyy/mm/dd/HH` format.

Then I created a crawler that will search for data into this bucket and configured it as follow:

[image: Crawler configuration]

After running the crawler, it creates a table with the following schema:

```
| #   | Column name   | Data type | Key           |
| --- | -----------   | --------- | ------------- |
| 1   | numberissues  | int       |               |
| 2   | group         | string    |               |
| 3   | createdat     | string    |               |
| 4   | companyunitid | string    |               |
| 5   | partition_0   | string    | Partition (0) |
| 6   | partition_1   | string    | Partition (1) |
| 7   | partition_2   | string    | Partition (2) |
| 8   | partition_3   | string    | Partition (3) |
```

If I rename the `partition-*` to their right counterparts `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour`, the table is ready for me to use.

However, if the crawler runs again, the schema revets the column names to the original `partition-*`.

I know this would work for Hive partition schemas `year=2018/month=04...`, but I want to know if it's possible to "hint" Glue about the partition field names.

Another alternative would be trying to change the Firehose prefixing, but I couldn't find anything that suggests this is even possible.

Comment: I understand your situation. Unfortunately Glue Follows Hive style of partitioning but kinesis firehose Doesn't write in such  format.  At this point in time i think we cant do any thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case you can set the "Ignore the change and don't update the data catalog" option.

Then you can rename the columns. This will allow the crawler to detect new partitions on the next run but keep therenamed names.

Comment: It seems so obvious now that this would work that I'm embarassed. Thanks a lot, @RicardoMayerhofer

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to specify a custom format for the S3 prefixes written by Firehose. To comply with the Hive style of partitions, you can use this syntax in your prefix:

```
beginning_of_prefix/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/
```

Example output:

```
beginning_of_prefix/year=2021/month=09/day=03/hour=16/
```

This will enable your Glue crawler to recognize the names of the partitions.

In a bit more details, the `!{namespace:value}` syntax AWS introduced allows accessing the timestamp that Firehose uses for partitioning and printing it into the prefix. This is done by specifying `timestamp` as a namespace, and a valid Java DateTimeFormatter string as the value. Note that:

> When evaluating timestamps, Kinesis Data Firehose uses the approximate arrival timestamp of the oldest record that's contained in the Amazon S3 object being written.

And that:

> If you specify a prefix that doesn't contain a timestamp namespace expression, Kinesis Data Firehose appends the expression !{timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd/HH/}to the value in the Prefix field.

(So if you don't use the `timestamp` namespace, the old way of partitioning is used)

Other namespaces also enable partitioning by firehose error type for the error output prefix for example.

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-custom-prefixes-for-amazon-s3-objects/)

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/s3-prefixes.html)